# AudioKit AKSampler makes strange feedback noise

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm using AudioKit AKSampler in my app to play piano sound, and it's working fine on my phone(iPhone 5), but when I checked on other phones(iPhone8, iPhone6) the sampler makes a strange feedback sound and a strange noise in the background.

Is this something you are familiar with? Is it the OS version number, or the device?
Any help?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code that is not working properly?
Also iOS versions used could be useful to help you.